# How to know which compiler is used to compile Python programs?

Tags: linux, python

How can I know which compiler is used when I type `python myapp.py` in terminal?

Comment: Related from Stack Overflow: [how to check which compiler was used to build Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15350780/12892)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask it.

```
$ python -V
Python 2.6.4
```

Comment: Is it the compiler name or just the python version?

Comment: The compiler is CPython. Jython is invoked as `jython` or some variant thereof, and IronPython is invoked as `IronPython.exe`.

Comment: Is there a command to get `CPython`?

Comment: Yes. The command is `python`.

Comment: `python` is not a compiler but an interpreter. @Nick.h CPython (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython) is a common python interpreter.

Comment: @Matteo: Incorrect. Python bytecompiles the source, then executes it on the appropriate VM.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: more or less. Generally Python (the Language) is an interpreted language. CPython is a byte code interpreter: compiles to byte code which is interpreted. There are also Python compilers which compile to machine code. I would try to differentiate them and not call `python` a compiler.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ which python

/usr/bin/python
```

This will tell you which python is being used.

Comment: It is possible that this command could differ from the version of python being used, as it only considers `$PATH`. It's better practise to use `type -p`.

Answer (score 1):

When you run

```
python myapp.py
```

in your terminal, no compiler is used. Python *interprets* the file myapp.py.

Comment: Incorrect. Python bytecompiles the script, and then runs the bytecode in its VM.